# I have been working with Photoshop. Do I need to learn at least some Illustrator? I am a web designer

Tags: adobe-photoshop, adobe-illustrator

I am web designer and I have been working with Photoshop. Sometimes I feel like I need to move to illustrator when need of graphic design came. Do I need to do that and how much?

Comment: If you need to ask than yes. Note that graphic design is not using a piece of software bu achieving whet you need.

Comment: Graphic design is quite broad... You don't 'need' illustrator for 'graphic design', but for certain things it might come in handy, for other things maybe not at all. You say you are a web designer, and then you say you do graphic design. Decide what you want and need to do, and learn how to do it.

Comment: hey janeDoe Thanks for your answer, but i need this graphic design thing for my self. As i am keen to explore in this field. I know i must sound you confused which i am. Just need little guidance.

Comment: If you were constructing houses would you *only* have a hammer? Or would you have a hammer *and* a screwdriver?

Answer (score 1):

Having knowledge about how to use the standard 3 programs for graphic design is a definite advantage. The 3 being: Photoshop, Illustrator and InDesign. There are obviously alternatives to each one which are more or less viable, the base skills are still very valuable.

Photoshop is for editing images, Illustrator for editing vector images and InDesign for layout. Photoshop is one of those weird do it all kind of programs, but Illustrator will do its thing a lot better.

As a web designer, the value of knowing InDesign is more debatable as it is primarily for print and not anywhere close to great for web work.

What you could look into is Adobe XD or Sketch.

Comment: The benefit of learning Illustrator is that illustrator is much closer to how a webpage works thanhow photoshop does things.

Comment: @joojaa I find that debatable... However I wouldn't recommend either, I would recommend Sketch to design webpages in.

Comment: @JaneDoe1337 perhaps. But understanding how a page device system works is important since a webpage is a page device system (which photoshop is not). The more automation you have on top the less you undertand the metal. Anyway i find that sketch is a bit of a twosided sword.

Comment: @JaneDoe1337 looks like you are in favor of sketch,, can you provide me some link where i can see your design work. if you dont mind